# Nanoseconds & Chrono C++

Tags: c++, datetime, c++-chrono

```
2018-10-01 00:06:16.700000000
```

I have a time series data file with timestamps as above. 
I need to convert this to nanoseconds from epoch, then I will need to add milli, micro, or nanos to the timestamp (shift). Finally for select records bring it back to the format above.

I am having trouble with the time point creation - and how to represent nanoseconds ... It works fine with micros.

Can I please request some assistance with the code fragment below .... and also once I have the nanoseconds from epoch - how do I go back to a timestamp like the one above.

```
std::string ts("23 01 2020 20:59:59.123456789");

XXXX (ts);

void XXXXX (string timestamp)
{
     stringstream temp_ss(timestamp);

     tm temp_time_object = {};

     temp_ss >> get_time (&temp_time_object, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S");

     chrono::system_clock::time_point temp_time_point = system_clock::from_time_t(mktime(&temp_time_object));
    // chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point temp_time_point1 = temp_time_point;

    auto  nsecs           =  stol (timestamp.substr (timestamp.find_first_of('.')+1,9));

// +++ This is where I GET stuck forming the time_point....
// I've tried this so many different ways .... 
// Is it that the system_clock cannot accept nanos? 


    temp_time_point += nanoseconds (nsecs);

     auto micro_from_epoch = duration_cast<nanoseconds> (temp_time_point.time_since_epoch()).count();

     cout << micro_from_epoch << endl;

}
```

Comment: please post the error message you get

Comment: the issue with the above code is that there is no += operator for nanoseconds. If I try to explicitly add using duration with ratio 1:100000000 - it still complains that I can't add this to a timepoint.

Comment: Is your string-based time stamp local time, or UTC?  If local time, your computer's current local time zone setting, or some other time zone?

Comment: assume all timestamps are GMT, UTC + 0

Answer (score 5):

> I am having trouble with the time point creation - and how to represent nanoseconds ... It works fine with micros.

This tells me that your `system_clock::time_point` has a precision of coarser than nanoseconds (on llvm it is microseconds, on Windows, 1/10 microseconds).  The easiest way to add nanoseconds to such a `time_point` is:

```
auto tp = temp_time_point + nanoseconds (nsecs);
```

This forms a `time_point` that is still `system_clock` based, but has the precision of the "common type" of `system_clock::duration` and `nanoseconds`, which in practice, will just be `nanoseconds`.

> assume all timestamps are GMT, UTC + 0

Now the problem is that `mktime` converts from a *local* `tm` to a UTC `time_t`.  But you are wanting to convert from a UTC field type, to a UTC serial type.

This is easily accomplished in C++20 (I know you don't have it yet, hear me out):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::nanoseconds>
XXXXX(std::string const& timestamp)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    istringstream temp_ss{timestamp};
    sys_time<nanoseconds> tp;
    temp_ss >> parse("%F %T", tp);
    return tp;
}

int
main()
{
    auto tp = XXXXX("2018-10-01 00:06:16.700000000");
    std::cout << tp.time_since_epoch().count() << "ns\n";
    std::string s = std::format("{:%F %T}", tp);
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

This converts the `string` to a `chrono::time_point<system_clock, nanoseconds>`, which is evidently different from your `system_clock::time_point` only in that your `system_clock::time_point` has precision coarser than `nanoseconds`.

Then `format` is used to convert the `time_point` back into a `string`.

Output:

```
1538352376700000000ns
2018-10-01 00:06:16.700000000
```

Now I know that a fully conforming C++20 `<chrono>` is a rare thing these days (it's coming).  Until it gets here, there is a [C++20 `<chrono>` preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that is compatible back to C++11.  It is free and open source.  And requires very few syntactic changes:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

date::sys_time<std::chrono::nanoseconds>
XXXXX(std::string const& timestamp)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    istringstream temp_ss{timestamp};
    sys_time<nanoseconds> tp;
    temp_ss >> parse("%F %T", tp);
    return tp;
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    auto tp = XXXXX("2018-10-01 00:06:16.700000000");
    std::cout << tp.time_since_epoch().count() << "ns\n";
    std::string s = format("%F %T", tp);
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1538352376700000000ns
2018-10-01 00:06:16.700000000
```

Comment: Your final example using date.h is amazingly simple and easy to follow. I just tried bringing it down to Mac OS. I get an error when executing: ./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh  .... will look at it again in the morning and see if I can fix the issue...  Errorsa re: eval: line 162: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Comment: For this use case, a CMake-based building tool (or any other package management tool) will cause more problems than it solves.  date.h is a header-only library.  Just include it and you're good to go.  If this still doesn't solve your problem, let me know and I'll help get you going.

Comment: so easy - header file worked perfectly.... where can i find a list of date format specifiers .. eg if my date is : delimited by '/' or some other format... I also noticed the library detects if you provide milliseconds - and it converts to nanoseconds, etc...  thank you for your help.

Comment: Here's all of the parsing flags: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#from_stream_formatting  The formatting flags are very similar and in a separate table just above this one.

Answer (score 1):

You work convert directly from text to nanosecond resolution.  There are essentially two key libraries:

- [CCTZ](https://github.com/google/cctz) by some Google engineers, though (like many projects) not a formally issued Google product
- [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) by Howard Hinnant who will probably answer here before I am done typing; his library is the basis of content for this in C++20

I have wrapped both for R (via Rcpp) and have plenty of examples. But there are also examples in the two repos so maybe start there?

So for lack of better immediate CCTZ examples here is one where the R package is used; you see the inputs:

```
R> library(RcppCCTZ)
R> example(parseDatetime)

prsDttR> ds <- getOption("digits.secs")

prsDttR> options(digits.secs=6) # max value

prsDttR> parseDatetime("2016-12-07 10:11:12",        "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")   # full seconds
[1] "2016-12-07 10:11:12 UTC"

prsDttR> parseDatetime("2016-12-07 10:11:12.123456", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E*S") # fractional seconds
[1] "2016-12-07 10:11:12.123456 UTC"

prsDttR> parseDatetime("2016-12-07T10:11:12.123456-00:00")  ## default RFC3339 format
[1] "2016-12-07 10:11:12.123456 UTC"

prsDttR> now <- trunc(Sys.time())

prsDttR> parseDatetime(formatDatetime(now + 0:4))               # vectorised
[1] "2020-05-01 02:16:27 UTC" "2020-05-01 02:16:28 UTC"
[3] "2020-05-01 02:16:29 UTC" "2020-05-01 02:16:30 UTC"
[5] "2020-05-01 02:16:31 UTC"

prsDttR> options(digits.secs=ds)
R>
```

The parser function called is (and ignore the R related bits)

```
Rcpp::DatetimeVector parseDatetime(Rcpp::CharacterVector svec,
                                   std::string fmt = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S%Ez",
                                   std::string tzstr = "UTC") {
    cctz::time_zone tz;
    load_time_zone(tzstr, &tz);
    sc::system_clock::time_point tp;
    cctz::time_point<cctz::sys_seconds> unix_epoch =
        sc::time_point_cast<cctz::sys_seconds>(sc::system_clock::from_time_t(0));

    // if we wanted a 'start' timer
    //sc::system_clock::time_point start = sc::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto n = svec.size();
    Rcpp::DatetimeVector dv(n, tzstr.c_str());
    for (auto i=0; i<n; i++) {
        std::string txt(svec(i));

        if (!cctz::parse(fmt, txt, tz, &tp)) Rcpp::stop("Parse error on %s", txt);

        // time since epoch, with fractional seconds added back in
        // only microseconds guaranteed to be present
        double dt = sc::duration_cast<sc::microseconds>(tp - unix_epoch).count() * 1.0e-6;

        // Rcpp::Rcout << "tp: " << cctz::format(fmt, tp, tz) << "\n"
        //             << "unix epoch: " << cctz::format(fmt, unix_epoch, tz) << "\n"
        //             << "(tp - unix.epoch).count(): " << (tp - unix_epoch).count() << "\n"
        //             << "dt: " << dt << std::endl;

        dv(i) = Rcpp::Datetime(dt);
    }

    return dv;
}
```

It looks over the incoming vector `svec` of strings and converts each.

*Edit:*  Here is another example using our [nanotime](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/nanotime) package which leverages and uses the CCTZ parser:

```
R> library(nanotime)
R> as.nanotime("2020-01-29 13:12:00.000000001 America/New_York")
[1] 2020-01-29T18:12:00.000000001+00:00
R>
```

Full 9 + 9 digits precision using underlying nanoseconds since epoch, fully interoperable with `std::chrono`.

Comment: Nope, you were too fast for me. :-)

Comment: Wow. That never happened before.  Thanks for being so attentive though!

Comment: in the code I added - micros and milliseconds works ... you can add that to a time point. i dont know how to create a time point with a full date_time which has nanosecond resolution. Your example above goes to micros - not to nano.

Comment: If I recall correctly the difference between micro and nano being available is left to the implementation / OS dependent. I live on Linux, and we *very much* have nanoseconds as I co-wrote a package [nanotime](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/nanotime) which leverages (Rcpp)CCTZ (and now also (Rcpp)Date) and it very nicely gets nanoseconds -- I use it daily these days.

Comment: Maybe you are referring to the example I showed, and I may have shown a bad one as it converts to R's default time types, and those _are_ microseconds.  Let me add a second one.